# Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Full Error Message: **Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)**.

I am trying to visualize a color band from a range of RGB values within a text document. However when I use the function below I get the above error and the color band looks like this.

[image: Color bank that is being output]

I have already tried a number of the solutions on here but I still can not get rid of the "Clipping Input" message.

Here is the code for plotting the color band:

```
def plot_colors(col_list, col_order, ratio = 10): 
    assert len(col_list) == len(col_order)
    img = np.zeros((ratio, len(col_list), 3))
    for i in range(0, len(col_list)):
        img[:, i, :] = col_list[col_order[i]]
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,6)) # figsize=(width,height) handles window dimensions
    axes.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')
    axes.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Here is where the code is called:

```
clustered_colours = data_scaled.sort_values(by=['Cluster']) #sorts colours by cluster

kmeans_cluster = clustered_colours[['Red','Green','Blue']].to_numpy() #Converts DataFrame to numpy array

order = list(range(ncolors)) #order from 0 to ncolours 

plot_colors(kmeans_cluster, order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib expects the data for `imshow` to be either in the range [0,1] if it's float or [0,255] if it's an integer.

First, check the `type(img)`, if it's float type then you'd have to convert the values in the range [0,1], if it's an integer, then [0,255]

```py
img = img/np.amax(img) # if float
img = np.array(img/np.amax(img)*255, np.int32) # if int
```